# Kohana 3.2 redirect in javascript

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-3.2

I need create redirect with delay after ajax action. A have code

```
setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.href="<?php echo  url::site('action'); ?>";
},2000);
```

in ajax success function. Of course I have session error in kohana. I have no idea how solve this problem.

ERROR:

> Session_Exception [ 1 ]: Error reading session data. ~ SYSPATH/classes/kohana/session.php [ 325 ] 
>   Uncaught exception '`ErrorException`' with message 'Unknown: The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,'' in Unknown on line 0

Always is same error if I use redirect without `$this->request->redirect('action');`

This is my **session config**

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') OR die('No direct script access.');

return array(
    'native' => array(
        'name' => 'mail',
        'lifetime' => 43200,
    ),
    'cookie' => array(
        'name' => 'mail',
        'encrypted' => TRUE,
        'lifetime' => 43200,
    ),
    'database' => array(
        'name' => 'mail',
        'encrypted' => TRUE,
        'lifetime' => 43200,
        'group' => 'default',
        'table' => 'sessions',
        'columns' => array(
            'session_id'  => 'session_id',
            'last_active' => 'last_active',
            'contents'    => 'contents'
        ),
        'gc' => 500,
    ),
);
```

Name exists. But I don't know what is depends name in config with error in change url without redirect.

Comment: Are you sure this is the code causing the error? How/when are you rendering/printing it?

Comment: Does it work to navigate to that URL manually in a browser?